# Custom Function Works in VBA and returns #VALUE "wrong data type" when called in a Excel Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UDF that counts how many clients and service worker has, or how many service workers a client has, for a given week. The data is two different ranges, one sorted by service worker they other sorted by client, to prevent having to sort first.

The code creates an array to record the row references of rows of a week that I'm searching for, then goes through at counts the last instance of a worker or client. The code works in VBA and returns a #VALUE in excel with "Error Checking' in Excel indicating the wrong data type. Using breaks, it appears the code fails when it gets to the range creation, this may be related to the creation of the array that takes row references from the range, or not.

I am wondering if I am some how trying to modify 'the state of excel". Thoughts on the problem and how the fix?

```
Public Function clientOrServiceWorkerCount(startWeek As Integer, endWeek As 
Integer, searchID As Long, outputType As Integer, sheetName As Variant) As 
Integer

    clientOrServiceWorkerCount = 0

    Dim WSMod111 As Worksheet
    Set WSMod111 = sheetName


    Dim rowOffset As Integer
    rowOffset = 3
    Dim endIndex As Integer
    endIndex = WSMod111.Cells(WSMod111.Rows.count, 13).End(xlUp).row - 
    rowOffset

    Dim tempRange As Range
    Set tempRange = WSMod111.Range("U4:Z" & endIndex)

    Dim tempArray() As Integer
    Dim weekNow As Integer
    Dim weekNext As Integer
    Dim ClientIDNow As Long
    Dim ClientIDNext As Long
    Dim serviceWorkerIDNow As Integer
    Dim serviceWorkerIDNext As Integer
    Dim arrayID As Integer
    Dim serviceWorkerCount As Integer
    Dim cLCount As Integer
    Dim colOffset As Integer
    Dim arrayCount As Integer

    arrayCount = 0

    ' Offset which columns to refer to based on the outputType value. 1 = 
    search for client then service workers
    ' 2 = search for service workers and then clients
    If outputType = 1 Then
        colOffset = 0
    End If

    If outputType = 2 Then
        colOffset = 3
    End If

    'Build the array for the week range of interest, defined by startWeek 
and endWeek
    For i = 0 To endIndex - 1
        weekNow = tempRange(i + 1, 1 + colOffset)
        arrayID = tempRange(i + 1, 2 + colOffset)

        If weekNow >= startWeek And weekNow <= endWeek And arrayID = 
        searchID Then
            ReDim Preserve tempArray(arrayCount)
            tempArray(arrayCount) = i + 1
            arrayCount = arrayCount + 1

            'Print the results to the worksheet to check answers
            tempRange.Cells(arrayCount, 8) = tempArray(arrayCount - 1)
        End If
    Next i

   For n = 0 To arrayCount - 1

        weekNow = tempRange(tempArray(n), 1 + colOffset)
        serviceWorkerIDNow = tempRange(tempArray(n), 2 + colOffset)
        ClientIDNow = tempRange(tempArray(n), 3 + colOffset)

        'Debugging printing

        'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 9) = weekNow
        'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 11) = serviceWorkerIDNow
        'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 13) = ClientIDNow

        If n < arrayCount - 1 Then

            weekNext = tempRange(tempArray(n + 1), 1 + colOffset)
            serviceWorkerIDNext = tempRange(tempArray(n + 1), 2 + colOffset)
            ClientIDNext = tempRange(tempArray(n + 1), 3 + colOffset)

            'Debugging printing
            tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 10) = weekNext
            tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 12) = serviceWorkerIDNext
            tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 14) = ClientIDNext

        End If

        If outputType = 1 Then
            If ClientIDNow <> ClientIDNext Or n = arrayCount - 1 Then
                cLCount = cLCount + 1
            End If
        End If

        If outputType = 2 Then
            If serviceWorkerIDNow <> serviceWorkerIDNext Or n = arrayCount - 
            1 Then
                serviceWorkerCount = serviceWorkerCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Return the count of either the clients (outputType=1) or the serviceWorkerinators (outputType=2)
    If outputType = 1 Then
        clientOrServiceWorkerCount = cLCount
    End If

    If outputType = 2 Then
       clientOrServiceWorkerCount = serviceWorkerCount
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Why `outputType As Byte` and not `Int`? Anyway, if it isn't 1 or 2, the return value is not defined. To be sure set `clientOrServiceWorkerCount = 0` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: A usf called from the worksheet cannot change the value of any cells but itself.

Comment: Hey Scott Craner, I don't think the code is changing any other cell than where it's called from. Unless you're referring to the debugging printing...? "Noting" out the debugging lines doesn't make a difference to the in-cell result, still getting a #VALUE.

Comment: @AntonyDeckepiphanied You have a lot of `tempRange.Cells(...) = ...` in that function.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a user-defined function on the sheet, but your UDF has content that changes the value of the cell. This can not be done by applying a function directly to the sheet, so an error occurs.

```
    'Debugging printing
    tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 10) = weekNext
    tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 12) = serviceWorkerIDNext
    tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 14) = ClientIDNext
```

Using your function inside a procedure works as shown below.

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As Integer
    c = clientOrServiceWorkerCount(2, 3, 1, 1, "Sheet2")
    Range("r1") = c

End Sub
```

If you comment out your problematic code, the result works well on the sheet.

```
Public Function clientOrServiceWorkerCount( _
        startWeek As Integer, _
        endWeek As Integer, _
        searchID As Long, _
        outputType As Integer, _
        sheetName As Variant) As Integer

    clientOrServiceWorkerCount = 0

    Dim WSMod111 As Worksheet
    Set WSMod111 = Sheets(sheetName)'<~~ Your code should change like this.


    Dim rowOffset As Integer
    rowOffset = 3
    Dim endIndex As Integer
    endIndex = WSMod111.Cells(WSMod111.Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row - rowOffset

    Dim tempRange As Range
    Set tempRange = WSMod111.Range("U4:Z" & endIndex)

    Dim tempArray() As Integer
    Dim weekNow As Integer
    Dim weekNext As Integer
    Dim ClientIDNow As Long
    Dim ClientIDNext As Long
    Dim serviceWorkerIDNow As Integer
    Dim serviceWorkerIDNext As Integer
    Dim arrayID As Integer
    Dim serviceWorkerCount As Integer
    Dim cLCount As Integer
    Dim colOffset As Integer
    Dim arrayCount As Integer

    arrayCount = 0

    ' Offset which columns to refer to based on the outputType value. 1 = search for client then service workers
    ' 2 = search for service workers and then clients
    If outputType = 1 Then
        colOffset = 0
    End If

    If outputType = 2 Then
        colOffset = 3
    End If

    'Build the array for the week range of interest, defined by startWeek and endWeek
    For i = 0 To endIndex - 1
        weekNow = tempRange(i + 1, 1 + colOffset)
        arrayID = tempRange(i + 1, 2 + colOffset)

        If weekNow >= startWeek And weekNow <= endWeek And arrayID = searchID Then
            ReDim Preserve tempArray(arrayCount)
            tempArray(arrayCount) = i + 1
            arrayCount = arrayCount + 1

            'Print the results to the worksheet to check answers
            'tempRange.Cells(arrayCount, 8) = tempArray(arrayCount - 1)
        End If
    Next i

   For n = 0 To arrayCount - 1

        weekNow = tempRange(tempArray(n), 1 + colOffset)
        serviceWorkerIDNow = tempRange(tempArray(n), 2 + colOffset)
        ClientIDNow = tempRange(tempArray(n), 3 + colOffset)

        'Debugging printing

        'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 9) = weekNow
        'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 11) = serviceWorkerIDNow
        'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 13) = ClientIDNow

        If n < arrayCount - 1 Then

            'weekNext = tempRange(tempArray(n + 1), 1 + colOffset)
            'serviceWorkerIDNext = tempRange(tempArray(n + 1), 2 + colOffset)
            'ClientIDNext = tempRange(tempArray(n + 1), 3 + colOffset)

            'Debugging printing
            'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 10) = weekNext
            'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 12) = serviceWorkerIDNext
            'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 14) = ClientIDNext

        End If

        If outputType = 1 Then
            If ClientIDNow <> ClientIDNext Or n = arrayCount - 1 Then
                cLCount = cLCount + 1
            End If
        End If

        If outputType = 2 Then
            If serviceWorkerIDNow <> serviceWorkerIDNext Or n = arrayCount - 1 Then
                serviceWorkerCount = serviceWorkerCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Return the count of either the clients (outputType=1) or the serviceWorkerinators (outputType=2)
    If outputType = 1 Then
        clientOrServiceWorkerCount = cLCount
    End If

    If outputType = 2 Then
       clientOrServiceWorkerCount = serviceWorkerCount
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Dy.Lee. I made the fix, Code updated. I tried passing the sheet in and not passing it into the function. Nether way makes a difference to the #VALUE error.

Comment: Actually, your suggestion causes a run time error. Changed my code back.

Comment: @AntonyDeckepiphanied, I am glad that you have solved it well.

Answer (score 0):

Dy.Lee, I commented out my debugging printing using your suggestion:

```
    For n = 0 To arrayCount - 1

        weekNow = tempRange(tempArray(n), 1 + colOffset)
        serviceWorkerIDNow = tempRange(tempArray(n), 2 + colOffset)
        ClientIDNow = tempRange(tempArray(n), 3 + colOffset)

        'Debugging printing
        'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 9) = weekNow
        'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 11) = serviceWorkerIDNow
        'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 13) = ClientIDNow

        If n < arrayCount - 1 Then

            weekNext = tempRange(tempArray(n + 1), 1 + colOffset)
            serviceWorkerIDNext = tempRange(tempArray(n + 1), 2 + colOffset)
            ClientIDNext = tempRange(tempArray(n + 1), 3 + colOffset)

            'Debugging printing
            'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 10) = weekNext
            'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 12) = serviceWorkerIDNext
            'tempRange.Cells(1 + n, 14) = ClientIDNext
```

And it works fine. I also updated the Sheet("") reference you made and am not receiving the compile error anymore. I had no idea that my debugging code was breaking a rule of "a function referenced in a cell cannot change anything but that referenced cell" - as I didn't know the rule existed.
Thank you so much for your help, I've been bashing my head on my desk for weeks trying to work out what was wrong.
Regards, Antony